# How to use jQuery in Netsuite?

Tags: jquery, netsuite

I am using netsuite. I want to use jquery in netsuite. Please help.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. It doesnt work like this, you need to showcase your effort eg., code or analysis. check here for more guidelines on how to post a question ,http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: dreamweaver - Sometimes "I have no idea where to start" type questions should be allowed.  But I do get you.  But both answers were exactly what I needed.  Which makes this a good question ;)

Answer (score 11):

You do not have to do anything at all; jQuery is included by default on all NetSuite pages. You can access it in any Client script; it will not work in server-side scripts. Be aware that you have to reference it using `jQuery` instead of `$`, e.g.

```
jQuery('#myElementId').hide()
```

Comment: I want to use jQuery for .autocomplete() function. I tried your answer in NetSuite but its not working. Please tell me how to use jQuery .autocomplete() function in NetSuite. I am getting "JS_Exception TypeError jQuery().autocomplete not a function" as a error message. 

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `autocomplete` is not a `jQuery` method; it is a *jQuery UI* method (https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/). NetSuite *does not* include jQuery UI. If you are trying to include jQuery UI (or any other third-party library, for that matter), the process is this: 1) Download the source of the library you want to use (preferably a minified version) 2) Upload the library source file(s) to the File Cabinet, probably under a place like `SuiteScripts\lib\` 3) Add the uploaded source file(s) as *Libraries* on your Script record

Answer (score 2):

As per my finding, Netsuite till now hasn't provided any straight forward way (API) to implement jQuery in SuiteScripts. So, you need to follow a deceitful way to get the jQuery stuffs done in your Netsuite screen.

In this Tip I'm going to show how to use a 'jAlert' in Netsuite screen, lets see how it goes:-

1) In this example we need 3 files:- 
    -jquery.min.js 
    -jquery.alert.js 
    -jquery.alert.css 
You can host these files in your Netsuite account (File Cabinet) or use any CDN to refer.

2) Create a Client script .js file whose function will be called in the 'Page Init' function. In this function you can write code to add the above 3 files into thehtml DOM of the Netsuite pages.

```
function OnPageInit() 
{ 
    AddJavascript('http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.min.js', 'head'); 
    var t = setTimeout("AddJavascript('https://system.netsuite.com/core/media/media.nl?id=253&c=TSTDRV896291&h=c3fc87f394f396552e09&_xt=.js', 'body')", 3000); 
    AddStyle('https://system.netsuite.com/core/media/media.nl?id=254&c=TSTDRV896291&h=50d488b82c3c3ed7263c&_xt=.css', 'head'); 
} 

function AddJavascript(jsname, pos) 
{ 
    var tag = document.getElementsByTagName(pos)[0]; 
    var addScript = document.createElement('script'); 
    addScript.setAttribute('type', 'text/javascript'); 
    addScript.setAttribute('src', jsname); 
    tag.appendChild(addScript); 
} 

function AddStyle(cssLink, pos) 
{ 
    var tag = document.getElementsByTagName(pos)[0]; 
    var addLink = document.createElement('link'); 
    addLink.setAttribute('type', 'text/css'); 
    addLink.setAttribute('rel', 'stylesheet'); 
    addLink.setAttribute('href', cssLink); 
    tag.appendChild(addLink); 
}
```

In the 'OnPageInit' function, we are first adding the 'jquery.min.js' (google CDN) and then we are using 'setTimeout' method for doing a time out of few seconds before adding the 2nd script. This is because, when the page gets loaded it will first download the 'jquery.min.js' script might take some time, for this reason when the second script 'jquery.alert.js' gets loadedit might show 'jquery undefined' error. To avoid this we can use the 'setTimeout' to delay the adding of the 'jquery.alert.js' script in the page's DOM. After that the CSS is also added to it. In this code we have hosted the 'jquery.alert.js' and 'jquery.alert.css' in the Netsuite's 'File Cabinet' folder.

3) Now deploy the client script. Lets say you have deployed it for 'Customer' record. Now, we can test if 'jAlert' is working for the Customer record screen or not.

4) Suppose, you write a client script function which will be called in the 'Save Record' event of the 'Customer' screen.

```
function OnSaveRecord() 
{ 
    jAlert('Custom Alert Box Test', 'This is a jAlert Box!'); 
}
```

5) Now test in the Customer screen if both the 'Page Init' and 'Save Record' functions are working fine or not.

If you have got some other tricks of using jQuery in Netsuite's SuiteScripts then please do mention below.

Comment: I tried this...  AND IT   WORKS!  Thank you Krooy_mans!  One or two things -- no need to include jquery -- its there!  And no need to add timing -- append child will order the scripts or css files one after the other which is all that is needed.